# SSIS script: Associating 2 records (one to many relationship) using CRM 4.0 (SDK) web reference

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, ssis

How can i link 2 records using a C sharp script in SSIS in a one to many relationship?

There is some good info out there to do this using CRM 2011 with EntityReference OR Relationship Classes. Unfortunately i cannot use these classes as i am doing this in SSIS 2008 .

Perhaps this can be done with a Lookup or Moniker but usure of detail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb957132.aspx) class from Crm 4 its pretty easy to build a relationship for a 1 to Many, its just like setting any other attribute really.

To get the guid of the another record from Crm you will need to issue a [RetrieveMultiple with a QueryExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb929002.aspx).

For example:

```
//Build the QueryExpression, the condition should give us a single record
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("contact");
query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("someidfield", ConditionOperator.Equal, "ABC123");

BusinessEntityCollection entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

//In theory we could get multiple records here, but we will assume we only get the one
DynamicEntity contact = (DynamicEntity)entities.BusinessEntities.First();
Guid existingContactId = (Guid)contact["contactid"];

Lookup lookupToExisitingContact = new Lookup();
lookupToExisitingContact.Value = existingContactId;
lookupToExisitingContact.type = "contact";

DynamicEntity newContact = new DynamicEntity("contact");
newContact["firstname"] = "James";
newContact["parentcontactid"] = lookupToExisitingContact;

service.Create(newContact);
```

Comment: Great. That makes sense. Any suggestions if i do not know the Guid of the other entity but do know the value of another field in that entity record (which is unique value). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I use both the business id and guid. See below. It still needs some work but i feel like i am going in the right direction.

First Merge Join and split checks if order already exist in CRM. In my case if it does than I don't want to take any action. The second Merge Join 1 actually does nothing but just gets the GUID of the contact using business key.

[image]